# C Programming Sending File over Socket issues

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I'm trying to setup a client and a server program where the client can download a file from the server.
I have got the client to download a .txt file however, the .txt file is only created, none of the data within it is transferred.

I've figured out the error is either from when the server sends the size of the file to the client OR the client is failing to recognize where the EOF is.

This is my server side code:

```
int send_all(int clientSocket, const void *buffer, int len) {
  const char *pbuf = (const char *) buffer;

  while(len > 0) {
    int sent = send(clientSocket, pbuf, len, 0);
    printf("%d\n", sent);
    if(sent < 1) {
      printf("%s\n", "Can't write to socket");
      return -1;
    }
    pbuf += sent;
    len -= sent;
  }
  return(0);
}


void SendFileToClient(int clientSocket, char* fileName) {

  //int offset;
  char buffer[0x1000];
  char temp[512] = "/root/Documents/";
  const char* filename = fileName;
  struct stat s;

  strcat(temp, filename);
  printf("%s\n", temp);

  //append the filenameonto the directory


  if(stat(temp, &s) == -1) {
    printf("%s\n", "Can't get file info");
    return;
  }

  FILE *file = fopen(temp, "rb");
  if(!file) {
    printf("%s\n", "Can't open the file for reading");
    return;
  }

  off_t size = s.st_size;
  off_t tmp_size = ntohl(size);
  if(send_all(clientSocket, &tmp_size, sizeof(tmp_size)) == 0) {
    while(size > 0) {
      printf("%ld\n", size);
      int rval = fread(buffer, 1, min(sizeof(buffer), size), file);
      if(rval < 1) {
        printf("%s\n", "Cant read from file");
        break;
      }

      if (send_all(clientSocket, buffer, rval) == -1)
        break;
      size -= rval;
    }
  }
  fclose(file);
}
```

This is my client side code:

```
int write_all(FILE *file, const void *buffer, int len) {
  const char *pbuf = (const char *) buffer;

  while (len > 0) {
    int written = fwrite(pbuf, 1, len, file);
    if(written < 1) {
      printf("%s\n", "Cant write to file");
      return -1;
    }
    pbuf += written;
    len -= written;
  }
  return 0;
}

int read_all(int clientSocket, void *buffer, int len) {
  char *pbuf = (char *) buffer;
  int total = 0;

  while (len > 0) {
    int rval = recv(clientSocket, pbuf, len, 0);
    if(rval < 0) {
      printf("%s\n", "Cant read from socket");
      return -1;
    }
    if(rval == 0) {
      printf("%s\n", "Socket disconnected");
      return 0;
    }

    pbuf += rval;
    len -= rval;
    total += rval;

  }
  return total;
}

void RecvFile(int clientSocket, const char* filename) {
  int rval;
  char buffer[0x1000];
  //printf("%s\n", filename);
  FILE *file = fopen(filename, "wb");
  if(!file) {
    printf("%s\n", "Cant open file for writing");
    return;
  }
  off_t size = 0;
  //this statement is not working
  if(read_all(clientSocket, &size, sizeof(size)) == 1) {
    size = ntohl(size);
    printf("%s%ld\n", "size: ", size);
    while(size > 0) {
      rval = read_all(clientSocket, buffer, min(sizeof(buffer), size));
      printf("%s%d\n", "rval: ", rval);
      if(rval < 1)
        break;
      if(write_all(file, buffer, rval) == -1) {
        printf("%s\n", "Cant write to file");
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  printf("%s\n", "closing file...");
  fclose(file);
}
```

My apologies if the code looks a bit messy - for some reason it didn't paste in with nice formatting.

I believe this is where part of the problem is, but even through various debugging I can't seem to get it to work :(

```
//this statement is not working
  if(read_all(clientSocket, &size, sizeof(size)) == 1) {
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why this loop `while(size > 0) {` on the client side?

Comment: Probably not the cause of the issue you observe, at least not for files <`INT_MAX` but your use of `int` and `size_t`  seems inconsistent.

Comment: The changing from int to size_t was purely debugging but had no affect

Comment: @alk Originally, there was no "read_all" function - this was put in place so that the client knew how big the file was, hence where the EOF is.

Comment: `recv()` and `send()` return `ssize_t` on most OS. They at least are able to return `-1`. So assigning the result to an `unsigned` as `size_t` is a bad idea,

Comment: Pump up the compiler's warning level and take the warning issues serious. Understand them and fix the code until they are gone. In C you mostly never want to cast to have any warning go away.